# What does "being watchful" mean in Colossians 4:2?

Tags: colossians, prayer, biblical-application

Colossians 4:2 states the following (emphasis added):

> Continue steadfastly in prayer, **being watchful** in it with thanksgiving. (ESV)

Here, Paul tells Christians to be "watchful" in prayer. What does this mean? Contextually, for what are Christians to be watchful in their prayers?

Answer (score 1):

The Greek word used for “**watchful**” in **Colossians 4:2** is: “γρηγορεύω (grégoreó)” which means: “to be awake, to watch, Mt. 26:38, 40, 41; Mk. 14:34; 37, 38; to be alive, 1 Thess. 5:10; met. to be watchful, attentive, vigilant, circumspect, Mt. 25:13; Mk. 13:35, et al.”  Source: https://www.billmounce.com/greek-dictionary/gregoreo

The **purpose** of being watchful in prayer is to have our minds set on sober realities, whether present or future.

A great example of this is when Jesus & His disciples were in the Garden of Gethsemane, cross reference(Matt 26:36):

> “Then Jesus went out and made his way, as he customarily did, to the
> Mount of Olives, and the disciples followed him.
>
> When he came to the place, he said to them, “***Pray that you will not
> fall into temptation***.”
>
> He went away from them about a stone’s throw, knelt down, and prayed,
> “Father, if you are willing, take this cup away from me. Yet not my
> will but yours be done.”
>
> [ Then an angel from heaven appeared to him and strengthened him. And
> in his anguish he prayed more earnestly, and his sweat was like drops
> of blood falling to the ground.]
>
> When he got up from prayer, he came to the disciples and found them
> sleeping, exhausted from grief. So he said to them, “Why are you
> sleeping? ***Get up and pray that you will not fall into temptation!***””
> ‭‭Luke‬ ‭22:39-46‬ ‭NET‬‬

As we just read and in relation to **Colossians 4:2**, the reason we are to be “**watchful** or vigilant in prayer is because we can fall into temptation, loose focus on spiritual realities, etc.

The similar word “γρηγορεῖτε (grēgoreite)“ in Matthew 24:42, means: “Keep watch” or “Be on the alert” in relation to the Lord’s Second Coming.  The same concept is essentially there.

Colossians 4:2 is about being “**watchful**” to our spiritual duties as Christians.

Not only in prayer, but in our mentality we are to have the following, as examples listed here:

1.

> “Therefore, **get your minds ready for action by being fully sober**,
> and set your hope completely on the grace that will be brought to you
> when Jesus Christ is revealed.” ‭‭1 Peter‬ ‭1:13‬

2. 

> Now the end of all things draws near. **Therefore be self-controlled
> and sober-minded for your prayers**. 1 Peter 4:7

3. 

> “But  take heed to yourselves, lest your hearts be weighed down with
> carousing, drunkenness, and  cares of this life, and that Day come on
> you unexpectedly. For  it will come as a snare on all those who dwell
> on the face of the whole earth. ***Watch therefore, and  pray always*** that
> you may  be counted  worthy to escape all these things that will come
> to pass, and  to stand before the Son of Man.” Luke 21:34-36

Luke is especially reflective of Colossians 4:2, we can ask: “***Why do we have to be watchful in our prayers?***”

**Answer**: Because in Luke’s account, in order to escape all the things coming on the earth, our Lord commanded we **watch and pray** that we escape all these coming calamities & to stand before Him.

Peter says the “end of all things is at hand(near).

The Scripture is clear we are made for God & eternity, so being watchful is our duty & the opposite is being slothful, careless, and lazy.  (Ecclesiastes 3:11, Colossians 1:15-16)

Prayer isn’t merely about our desires, certainly some of it is, but prayer should be more “attentive” & “kingdom focused”.  The Lord’s Prayer does address our (needs), yet, it is also kingdom focused:

> “So pray this way: Our Father in heaven, may your name be honored, may
> **your kingdom come, may your will be done on earth as it is in heaven.**”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭6:9-10‬ ‭NET‬‬

**CONCLUSION**

1. The end of the age is near, so be watchful & pray always that we can stand before the Son of Man.
2. We pray in vigilance that we may not enter into temptation & sin.
3. We pray watchfully in anticipation of Jesus’ second coming.
4. We attentively pray that we would seek God’s Kingdom, His righteousness, & our needs. (Matt 6)
5. We pray to be delivered out of the hands of Satan’s attacks: (Matt 6:13)
6. We pray diligently to have our sins forgiven: (Matt 6:12,14,15)
7. We are to be watchful in prayer for mortification of sin lest we die: (Romans 8:12-13)

Etc…

Answer (score 0):

We are to watch that we remain in a prayerful spirit with our hearts directed to God at every moment. The following words say it so well:

> If you draw close to Jesus and seek to adorn your profession by a well-ordered life and godly conversation, your feet will be kept from straying into forbidden paths. If you will only watch, continually watch unto prayer, if you will do everything as if you were in the immediate presence of God, you will be saved from yielding to temptation and may hope to be kept pure, spotless, and undefiled till the last. If you hold the beginning of your confidence firm unto the end, your ways will be established in God; and what grace has begun, glory will crown in the kingdom of our God. The Adventist Home p. 338. Ellen G. White.

Living as in the presence of God in a sinful world may seem like a tall order, but God's Spirit is sent to accompany us and the only way to talk to God is through prayer.

> The darkness of the evil one encloses those who neglect to pray. The whispered temptations of the enemy entice them to sin; and it is all because they do not make use of the privileges that God has given them in the divine appointment of prayer. Why should the sons and daughters of God be reluctant to pray, when prayer is the key in the hand of faith to unlock heaven's storehouse, where are treasured the boundless resources of Omnipotence? Without unceasing prayer and diligent watching, we are in danger of growing careless, and of deviating from the right path. The adversary seeks continually to obstruct the way to the mercy-seat, that we may not by earnest supplication and faith obtain grace and power to resist temptation. The Review and Herald, December 8,  1904, par. 6. Ellen G. White.

The above words bring out to me the importance of prayer. I think this is what Colossians 4:2 is also trying to tell us.